# Laravel 5 Read Only View Model with polymorphic Relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, polymorphism

Sometimes we use MySql Views to organize related tables to make it easier to search and sort. For example if you have Posts with a Status, and a Source.

```
Post
    subject
    body
    source_id
    status_id

Status
    id
    label
    other_field

Source
    id
    label
    other_field


View
   create view read_only_posts as
   SELECT statuses.label as status, sources.label as source, posts.*
   from posts
   left join statuses on statuses.id = posts.status_id
   left join sources on sources.id = posts.source_id
```

Then we have the Post model and an extra model:

```
// Post.php
class Post extends Model
{
    //
}

// ReadOnlyPost.php
class ReadOnlyPost extends Post
{
    protected $table = 'read_only_posts';
}
```

This is nice because now you can directly sort or filter on Status or Source as a string not the id's. You can also include the 'other_field'.

But we have a problem that I need help with.  If you have a polymorphic many-to-many relationship on Posts, I can't get it to work on the read only version.  For example if you have polymorphic tags:

```
// Post.php Model
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
}
```

The problem is when you filter a post (using the read only model) with a specific tag you get sql like this:

> select count(*) as aggregate from `read_only_posts` where exists (select * from `tags` inner join `taggables` on `tags`.`id` = `taggables`.`taggable_id` where `read_only_posts`.`id` = `taggables`.`taggable_type` and `taggables`.`taggable_type` = 'read_only_posts' and `label` = 'test')

As you can see the problem is the **`taggables`.`taggable_type` = 'read_only_posts'**.

I can't find a way to override the morph type for a model.  (I am on laravel 5.4 and the [MorphClass](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/search.html?search=MorphClass) isn't there anymore).  The morph map is an associative array so you can't do this:

```
// AppServiceProvider
public function boot()
{
    Relation::morphMap([
        'posts' => Post::class,
        'posts' => ReadOnlyPost::class, <--- Can't do this
```

My stupid fix is when I attach a tag to a post I also attach it to ready_only_posts, which is kind of a mess.

Anyone else uses Views for read only models?  Anyone have a better way to overriding the many to many polymorphic type for a specific model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code, I believe this might work.

```
class ReadOnlyPost extends Posts
{
    public function getMorphClass() {
         return 'posts';
    }
}
```

In theory you should need to have the `Posts` model/table listed in the morph map, since the system will auto generate the type of "posts" for it based on naming.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is gone in 5.4. https://laravel.com/api/5.4/search.html?search=MorphClass

Comment: @Patrick_Finucane Okay I took a look through the code, and I believe the above might work.  Don't have a project setup right now to test it though

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't map both in the morphMap. See the bottom of my question.

Comment: Ok. My reading skills are terrible. Sorry.  Does the overriding of 'getMorphClass' work?  Also, do you need to mention the Post class in morph map?  The default would be 'posts' right?